# Multiple line pyplot, way to display without the lines being too bunched together

Tags: python, matplotlib, linegraph

So i have the current result of a graph i built

[image]

As you can see the multiple plots, are a little to bunched up together and i would like to separate them, would appreciate some help on the how? I tried using ylim method but didnt quite aide me they are still too bunched together.

Source code

```
for k,i in clean_font_data.to_dict().items():
    plt.plot(list(i.keys()),list(i.values()), label = k[1],marker='o')
    
plt.legend(title="Legenda",fontsize=7)
plt.title('Conversão Diaria')
plt.xlabel('Datas',fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel('Conversão',fontsize = 12)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Sample of a plots data:

```
attendance bot
['2022-06-01', '2022-06-02', '2022-06-03', '2022-06-04', '2022-06-05', '2022-06-06']
[15.9, 17.99, 17.24, 12.75, 22.89, 24.69]
```

Comment: What are you seeking for? another way to represent your data? if plot are condense toward lower value, you may try to diplay them on a log chart with `plt.yscale('log')`

Comment: That is exactly, what i am seeking. Well i will try your recomendation thanks

Comment: Although i think the scale is not supposed to be on such a low level, i just want the lower ended plots to be more visible without eliminatin the top one, i am taking a loot at custom scaling may be that will help me